# Send HTTP Request from local server to remote server

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

I am using BaseX version 9.5, I am trying to send HTTP request from local to remote server to read database, but not getting the response.

```
let $server := 'http://10.102.xxx.xxx:8984/rest/'
let $sendreq    := (http:send-request(
              <http:request method='POST' username='admin' password='admin' send-authorization='true'
               href='{$server}' auth-method='Basic'>
               <http:body media-type="application/xml">
               {
                  collection('test')/*
               }</http:body>
                </http:request>
              ))[2]
 return $sendreq
```

Can anyone suggest how can I send query to remote server so that I could read and query to remote server database from my local server?

Comment: I understand you want to execute `collection('test')/*` on the remote. But it is currently executed on your local instance.

Comment: What is going wrong here, how can I send this query to remote server?

Answer (score 0):

To execute your query on a remote instance of basex

```xml
http:send-request(
  <http:request method='POST'
    href='{$remote-server-rest-endpoint}'
    username='{$remote-instance-user}'
    password='{$remote-instance-user-password}'
    send-authorization='true'
    auth-method='Basic'>
    <http:body media-type="application/xml">
      <query xmlns="http://basex.org/rest">
        <text><![CDATA[
          declare variable $a as xs:integer external;
          declare variable $b as xs:integer external;
          <mult>{ $a * $b }</mult>
        ]]></text>
        <variable name="a" value="21"/>
        <variable name="b" value="2"/>
      </query>
    </http:body>
  </http:request>
)
```

Adapted from the example found in the docs: https://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST#POST_Method

Comment: Thank you for looking this, i tried your given solution, it is throwing error.   "[experr:HC0002] Conversion failed: "" (Line 10975): The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed"

Comment: Without seeing the actual request element I cannot help you.

Comment: the same code I am running which you have given above, nothing changed.

Comment: let $remote-server-rest-endpoint := 'http://10.102.200.111:8984/rest/'
let $sendreq  := http:send-request(
  <http:request method='POST' href='{$remote-server-rest-endpoint}' username='admin'password='admin'
                        send-authorization='true'
                       auth-method='Basic'>
                    <http:body media-type="application/xml">
                      <query>
                        <text>collection('test')</text>
                        <context />
                      </query>
                    </http:body>
  </http:request>
)[2]
return $sendreq

Comment: maybe start with a _very_ simple request `1+1` and see if that is returned.

Comment: I modified my answer to use an example from the docs

Comment: it is returning